# EJBTransactionRolledBackException - Huge amount of data - TypedQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I have a function that looks like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="persistence-unit")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public List<Person> (Integer startPosition, Integer maxResult)
{

TypedQuery<Person> findAllQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINT p FROM Person p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.cityByCity LEFT JOIN FETCH p.userByUser ORDER BY p.id", Person.class);

if(startPosition != null){
findAllQuery.setFirstResult(startPosition);
]
if(maxResult!=null){
findAllQuery.setMaxResults(maxResult);
}
return findAllQuery.getResultList

}
```

I have person, city and user objects.

When I try to bring lets say 50k persons, it works okay. But if I try 150k persons it just doesnt finish and gives EJBTransactionRolledBackException: Transaction rolled back. I give start position as 0 and 5 as max result so it should bring first 5 person but it just doesnt end and give the exception.

I  believe TypedQuery bringing all of the results and then trying to get the first 5 is the reason of the issue. But on the other hand I'm not sure TypedQuery works like that. If its working like that, it really needs an update:D

Comment: Try to get more out of your logs what is the root cause for this exception, timeout perhaps? And from where the root cause comes. I am not an expert and also unfamiliar with FETCH (only I know it triggers eager fetch somehow) but it might be that database engine needs to do extensive calculations with DISTINCT and JOINS. You could try to find out the problematic join / crfeate indexes. So I would not blame JPA/Hibernate on the first thought.

Comment: Can you enable SQL logging & check the generated native query whether limit/max result is specified.